# Firefox simple extension to post data

Tags: jquery, node.js, firefox, firefox-addon

I've created a simple extension for Firefox. Now I've tried to send user selected text. On the Mozilla web site I can not find any document about sending REST data via POST or for example httpClient. I want to send selected text to server and get that via server to parse it.

Comment: Are you using firefox sdk? If you are then they have a nxhr module: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request if you are using regular bootstrap you can use nsiXMLHttpRequest module: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/30e44f6d88423bf5096e

Comment: @Noitidart hi sir. excuse me, how to post string  by `Request` method? is this code correct ? `Request({
  url: "http://my-site.com",
  content:"HELLO WORLD",
  contentType:"text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    
  }
}).post();`

Comment: like this: https://github.com/willscott/grunt-jasmine-firefoxaddon/blob/844e85ec6c63e8886d2d218663dc3132e7286da4/tasks/jasmine-firefoxaddon/index.js#L18-L33

Comment: @Noitidart thank you very much sir. please reply to post and let me to accept and upvote that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var req = Request({
    url: 'http://localhost:9989/put',
    content: btoa(JSON.stringify(res)),
    overrideMimeType: "text/plain; charset=latin1",
    onComplete: function (response) {
      pendingReports -= 1;
      if (onFinish && pendingReports === 0) {
        onFinish();
      }
    }
  });
  req.post();
```

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS FOR MOZILLA WEB EXTENSION**

If you want to send data without use of jQuery then

```
var ajaxData = new FormData();
ajaxData.append('textData', "Your text Data");

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", YOUR_API_URL);
http.send(ajaxData);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) { 
 //SUCCESS
  }
}

http.onerror = function () {
      //ON error 
    };
```

If you want to use jQuery then

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: YOUR_API_URL,
        data: {
            "textData": "your text data,

        },
        success: function(data) {
          //SUCCESS
        },
        error: function(err) {
            //ERRROR
        }
```